# Why my unit test fails altough method works good?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I try to count time interval. I parse String date into Date object for some pattern.

```
public static float countTimeAgo(String timestamp){

    // date pattern
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);

    // time interval
    float diff;

    try {
        // convert timestamp to given pattern
        Date timestampDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(timestamp);

        // get actual date and convert to pattern
        Date date = new Date();
        simpleDateFormat.format(date);

        // count difference in millis
        diff = date.getTime() - timestampDate.getTime();

        // convert millis to minutes
        diff = diff/(1000*60);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (diff < 0)
        return -1;

    else
        return diff;
}
```

When I put string "2018-03-08 23:28:07.807353" as argument while running my app, method is returning non -1 value. But when I run a test, it fails:

```
@Test
public void testCountTimeAgo(){

    String date = "2018-03-08 23:28:07.807353";
    assertTrue(PostTimeProvider.countTimeAgo(date) != -1);
}
```

AssertionError:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
```

Does somebody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

In your code -1 can be returned when the parsing fails or if the date was in future. You should check which one is happening in this case. Perhaps your device and the device running the unit tests have different time?

Comment: I changed my method to return -1 only when parse exception occurs. Test of my date string still returns -1, so it is parsing error.

Comment: I tried different tests. Seems like fail depends on value after dot in date string. When I put date "2018-03-08 23:28:07.000123" test is passed, but when value after dot is greater, example "2018-03-08 23:28:07.001234", test is failed.

Comment: In that case I suggest you modify the code to not catch the `ParseException`, or to print the details of it when it is caught. The description will hopefully tell you what was wrong.